# how to group and pivot columns to values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have result from my query like this on PostgreSQL:

| date | depart | blue_team | red_team | green_team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-11 | south | 2158 | 2832 | 2481 |
| 2023-08-11 | east | 6641 | 6714 | 6581 |
| 2023-08-11 | north | 1159 | 1512 | 1485 |
| 2023-08-11 | west | 8274 | 7131 | 8068 |

and i need to group team's in new column like `team_type` and sum values regard it.

So my prefered output should be like:
[image]

my sql script:

```
with res as (
select
    date,
    depart,
    case
        when team_name = 'blue' then scores
    end blue_team,
    case
        when team_name = 'red' then scores
    end red_team,
    case
        when team_name = 'green' then scores
    end green_team
from results)
select
    date,
    depart,
    sum(blue_team) blue_team,
    sum(red_team) red_team,
    sum(green_team) green_team
from res
group by 1,2
```

Comment: is it always these 3 team categories?

Comment: @eshirvana Yes, only these 3

Comment: then see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then simple `union all` would answer your question:

```
select date, depart, 'blue_team' as teamtype, blue_team as value from game_results
union all 
select date, depart, 'red_team' as teamtype, red_team as value from game_results
union all
select date, depart, 'green_team' as teamtype, green_team as value from game_results
```

or you can use `unnest` :

```
SELECT date, depart
, UNNEST(ARRAY['blue_team', 'red_team', 'green_team']) AS teamtype
, UNNEST(ARRAY[blue_team, red_team, green_team]) AS value
FROM game_results
```

| date | depart | teamtype | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-11 | south | blue_team | 2158 |
| 2023-08-11 | east | blue_team | 6641 |
| 2023-08-11 | north | blue_team | 1159 |
| 2023-08-11 | west | blue_team | 8274 |
| 2023-08-11 | south | red_team | 2832 |
| 2023-08-11 | east | red_team | 6714 |
| 2023-08-11 | north | red_team | 1512 |
| 2023-08-11 | west | red_team | 7131 |
| 2023-08-11 | south | green_team | 2481 |
| 2023-08-11 | east | green_team | 6581 |
| 2023-08-11 | north | green_team | 1485 |
| 2023-08-11 | west | green_team | 8068 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/11-FO2Vi)